# Spring Boot + PostgreSQL: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I have a problem when connect Spring Boot with PostgreSQL. I can't seem to make it work. If there's anything missing I can give it more to you but for now this is enough information

the full error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project resorts-restful-project: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

heres my configuration:

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/qwerty
spring.datasource.username=postgres spring.datasource.password=postgres@qwerty
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

my model:

```
package com.fvthree.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
public class Resort implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="resorts_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="location")
    private String location;

    @Column(name="contact_id")
    private Long contactId;

    public Resort() {
    }

    public Resort(Long id, String name, String location, Long contactId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.contactId = contactId;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public Long getContactId() {
        return contactId;
    }

    public void setContactId(Long contactId) {
        this.contactId = contactId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have all these properties set:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

And you have these annotations enabled on the class with main():

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I already fixed the problem.

application.properties file needs to be complete:

```
# Configure postgres

spring.jpa.database=POSTGRESQL
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/qweqwe
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=dontcopythis
```

i also add @EntityScan and @EnableJpaRepositories to the main :

```
package com.fvthree;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.fvthree.domain" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.fvthree.repository"})
public class ResortsRestfulProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ResortsRestfulProjectApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

(1) In your file `application.properties`, notice that `spring.datasource.username=postgres spring.datasource.password=postgres@qwerty` is 2 lines, not 1 line.

(2) Because this error:

> Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when
>   'hibernate.dialect' not set

You are missing
`hibernate.dialect=...`

For example, if you use PostgreSQL 9.5, it will be
`hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect`

Reference: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/package-summary.html

Comment: Is there a way to get org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect to work with spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.5.3.RELEASE ? It doesn't contain version of hibernate which would have that.

Comment: You should use latest PostgreSQL version, then use  `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect` not `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect`
Spring Boot 1.5.3.RELEASE use Hibernate managed dependence version 5.0.12.Final . See: 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/dialect/PostgreSQL95Dialect.html (section hibernate-orm) and
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix-dependency-versions

Comment: You must override managed dependency version. But it make instability for your application.